# What is the difference between expand(), grow() and fill() in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I am currently working with scene2d tables. But I am tired of using hit and trial to make the layout I wanted. Can anyone explain the meanings of expand, fill and grow? I need the behaviour like wrap_content and match_parent as in android.

Some code I tried is:

```
    Table contentTable = scoreDialog.getContentTable();
    contentTable.debugAll();

    Table topTable = new Table();
    topTable.debugAll();
    topTable.top();

    topTable.add(timeImage).colspan(2).pad(5);
    topTable.add(timeProgressBar).colspan(5).pad(5);
    topTable.add(bonusLabel).colspan(3).pad(5);
    topTable.row();
    topTable.add(alignImage).colspan(2).pad(5);
    topTable.add(alignProgressBar).colspan(5).pad(5);
    topTable.add(penaltyLabel).colspan(3).pad(5);

    contentTable.row();
    contentTable.add(topTable).colspan(10).pad(5).expandX().align(Align.center);
    contentTable.row();

    contentTable.add(scoreLabelDialog).colspan(10).pad(5).expandX().align(Align.center);
    contentTable.row();

    starsTable = new Table();
    starsTable.setHeight(50);
    contentTable.add(starsTable).pad(5).colspan(10).expandX().align(Align.center);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Expand**: expands the `cell` that the actor is currently placed in to occupy the largest possible area without changing other cells size. For example if the cell is `50 x 50` and there is `50px` of empty space to the sides of the cell it will resize to `100 x 50`. Only changes the size of the `cell`, not the `actor`.

**Fill**: makes the `actor` occupy the entire space of the `cell`. For example if the actor is `50 x 50` and the cell is `100 x 100` the actor will be resized to `100 x 100`. Only changes the size of the `actor` not the `cell`.

**Grow**: both expand and fill at the same time.